# Inserting spaces between cells

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following code that inserts two cells in a row. It works fine however these two values do not have any spaces in between. So I am trying to figure out how to add couple of spaces in between cells or just add a slash /

```
TableCell tc=new TableCell();
Label lb1= new Label();
lb1.Text=stg1
tc.Controls.Add(price);
tc.Controls.Add(lb1);
```

I want to insert some spaces or slash between cells on same row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should add columns to the table as a whole.
Otherwise add padding to the label (in one of many ways):

```
label.Padding = new Padding(10);
label.Padding = new Padding(left:10, top:10, right:10, bottom:10);
label.Padding.Left = 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use css class to do this. Then just apply CssClass to your control:

Here is css code:

```
.mySpacer
{
    border: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

Here is c code:

```
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        tc.CssClass = "mySpacer";
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the space html code `&nbsp;`